# On which factor (parameters) bandwidth is depend using FIO benchmarking of pmem

Tags: io, storage, benchmarking

I am doing FIO testing of /dev/pmem for sequential read with command using:

fio --name=readf --filename=/dev/pmem --iodepth=4 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --buffered=0 --groupreprting --timebased --bs=64k --size=10g --rw=read --norandommap --refillbuffers=1 --randrepeat=0 --runtime=300

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague and can be read as what does your maximum disk bandwidth depend on?

- Speed of the underlying device.
- State of the underlying device.
- Busyness of the system.
- Amount of I/O that can be sent down in tandem.
- How I/O is batched together.
- Block size chosen (disks generally have an optimal size).
- Whether the I/O is sequential or random.
- Whether there is other I/O happening to the same disk (e.g. SMART updates).
- Whether cache on the device is exhausted.
- Whether the device has to do maintenance.
- Size of caches.
- Amount of I/O put down.
- Compressibility of data.
- Configuration parameters of the OS.
- Configuration parameters of the hardware.
- Size of the region I/O is done within.

In the job given things that stand out are:

- The iodepth looks a bit low try boosting it until you don't get a benefit.
- setting norandommap is meaningless for a sequential job
- Setting both direct=1 and buffered=0 is redundant
- groupreprting and timebased are spelt incorrectly
- refillbuffers is also spelt wrong and you might get away with scramble_buffers with lower overhead but at the risk of less random data
- You might get some benefit from pinning fio to appropriate CPUs
- You might get some benefit submitting I/O in batches

Comment: I am getting more bw than expected, why this.. may be due to cache but i used all the parameter to handle it. But it give higher bw.

Comment: Pinning - http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-cpumask and what follows. Batching - http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-iodepth-batch-submit and what follows.

Comment: Re higher than expected bandwidths - too many possibilities and not enough information. For example, if you are reading back data that's "never" been written you can expect to get extraordinary speeds. If you are re-reading a small enough area then caching can indeed distort your results.

Comment: So how to avoid reading back data, and how to avoid rereading small area.. which parameter should i use? I m using above cmnd. Thanks

Comment: @Pushpendra http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-size explains how the `size` parameter controls the area too. Just so you know benchmarking SSDs properly is a lot of work - see http://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/SSS_PTS_Enterprise_v1.1.pdf which has a huge amount of detail about test methodology and discusses things like preconditioning. That's all I've got time for - good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time :-)